# Unable to start namenode in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, namenode

I am installing `Hadoop 2.7.3` on my Ubuntu 16.0.4 system. I am getting following error while trying to execute `start-dfs.sh`. I have checked all configuration files.

```
node@hellbot:~$ start-dfs.sh
17/01/28 20:46:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-node-namenode-hellbot.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-node-datanode-hellbot.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-node-secondarynamenode-hellbot.out
17/01/28 20:46:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the Logs problem is not with name node but it had something to do with your Hadoop library. Have you set the .bashrc file ?

Comment: There is no errors, its only a warning which won't restrict namenode from starting. Please post the actual error log if any.

Comment: I agree with @Krishas, I've seen this warning before and our cluster didn't experience an actual fault because of it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and help...hadoop is working fine now even with that warning message.